# Why a duck, in "ducked out"?

Tags: american-english, pop-culture

Maybe more a cultural question, about USA.

Not the same question as:

[to duck out to do something](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/358830/2643)

...this question is based on that, stop saying it's duplicated please :)

If "to duck out" is "to sneak out", why a duck? Do Americans see ducks as a "sneaky" animal?

I saw this in Avengers Endgame. Tony says to Strange "you should've ducked out".

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/duck) has for **duck²** *1 Lower the head or the body quickly to avoid a blow or missile or so as not to be seen.* Also *1.3 Evade or avoid (an unwelcome duty or undertaking)*. Also from [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/duck#etymonline_v_15956) *c. 1300, "to plunge into" (transitive); mid-14c., "to suddenly go under water and immediately withdraw"*. Because that is what ducks do.

Comment: Who remembers [Duck and Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_and_cover)?

Comment: @DjinTonic no, I've linked that one my question and got on from there.

Comment: Also "When his wife arrived in the emergency department, Reagan remarked to her, "Honey, I forgot to duck", borrowing boxer Jack Dempsey's line to his wife the night he was beaten by Gene Tunney." -- Wikipedia

Comment: @Lexico got it... It's a "duck in the water" context then.

Comment: A duck ducks. The OED traces the  bird  and the verb to the same origin, to *duck/dive* and then *duck out = back out*.

Answer (score 1):

Green’s Dictionary of Slang  suggests that the usage of duck in ***[duck out](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/xelmvty)*** meaning:

> 1. to make off, to leave, to abscond.
>
> - 1898   [US]    F. Norris Moran of the Lady Letty 15: *I’ve got to duck my nut or I’ll have the patrol boat after me.*

derives from the old sense of duck meaning  “to escape, to run off” as in:

***[do a/the duck](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/ahaciqy)*** (v.) (also do a duckaway)

> - 1896    [US]    F. Hutcheson Barkeep Stories 173: *‘Dey ’re sore ’cause I do me duckaway an’ dey t’ink dey ’ll just take a shot at me anyhow’.*

Comment: The OP already knows what the phrase means, and that is in any event, addressed in the question that the OP refers to. The question was **why** *duck*? What does ducking out have to do with ducks?

Answer (score 0):

There are two stages of metaphor here. Or maybe a half?

A duck is not a sneaky animal like a fox. But it has this common behavior of quickly putting its head underwater. This motion of dipping or diving, for any animal, humans presumably, was [historically](https://www.etymonline.com/word/duck) Old English 'ducan' which, by metaphor, came to be used for the animal.

The canonical image upon hearing the word 'duck' as a noun is the wading bird. If as a verb, canonically, it is the motion. But really, these are both pretty common so sure 'ducking out' could easily evoke the animal.

So the phrase 'to duck out' as in "I ducked out of the meeting to take a call" is metaphorical on the motion, to leave for a moment (or quietly leave altogether).

Comment: Needs reference.

Comment: @GEdgar see the etymonline reference under 'historically'